# iPhone: How to Get Location as in the App "Qype"

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, geolocation, mkmapview

I've discovered today the app "Qype" and now I'd like to know how I can build a function to locate myself like in quype.

For those who dont know this app: It's an app that shows you Cafés, Bars, Restaurants etc. near you. When I'm starting Qype there's a question: "Qype want to locate your position. Do you want to allow it?"

Are there any References from Apple or any tutorials to learn how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it just me or does "Qype" (pronounced "qwa-ipe") sound vaguely like a curse word? I might start using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get and use your location you should use [`CoreLocation`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/index.html) framework in your application.

"Appname want to locate your position. Do you want to allow it?" is just a standard message iphone system automatically shows when application attempts to use CoreLocation services for the first time.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is the CoreLocation sample from Apple. Here it is

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/LocateMe/index.html